# How to add shift + enter key to go next line and the Enter key for submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add `shift + enter` key to go next line, and just the `enter key` to trigger the submit button by using **JAVASCRIPT** only.

How to achieve it?

Also I wish to submit texts in multi line too ...
Thanks in advance

```js
function typo() {
  if (document.getElementById("myText").value.trim().length == 0) {
     document.getElementById("myText").focus();
    
  } 
  else 
  {
    var currentText = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var x = '<div><p class=bubble>' + document.getElementById("myText").value + '</p></div>';
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
    var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currentText + x;

    var z = document.getElementById('demo');
    z.scrollTop = z.scrollHeight;
   
    document.getElementById("myText").focus();  
  }
}
  
  var input = document.getElementById("myText");
  input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event)
   {
    event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && input.value.trim().length >0)
   {
    
      document.getElementById("btn-chat").click();

    }
  });
```

```html
  <div id="demo"></div>
 
<textarea class="widebox" type="text" id="myText" value=""></textarea>
<button onclick="typo()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: _“Also I wish to submit texts in multi line too”_ - that is default behavior for a textarea, so if that’s _not_ the case for you, you must have done something to make it otherwise …

Comment: But it submits as a single line text not as multi line...

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn’t. Much more likely that you are drawing wrong conclusions, because you misinterpreted what your output means. Please explain how exactly you have verified that this (allegedly) does behave this way.

Comment: You can run and see the it in code snippet . Also am new to this whole thing .Actually i tired to do something like a chat box where you can do multi line chat.

Comment: _“You can run and see the it in code snippet”_ - no I can’t, because that doesn’t even allow me to input a line break into the textarea. Plus, there is no actual “form submission” happening here to begin with, no one is sending anything anywhere, you are just reading the value using script. **Your mistake is not taking into account how HTML handles white space.** Instead of creating your `<p class=bubble>` dynamically, you could as well have the whole thing written statically in your HTML to begin with, including line breaks somewhere in the text content - the result would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Ask question = one question. For now on ;)

For first question, you have to control the default behavior

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e){
    // Enter was pressed + shift key
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey)
    {
        // prevent default behavior
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

For second question, you should add:

```
// "Enter" key on the keyboard is 13 keyCode
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot !